# represent bitmask value in JSON object

Tags: json, rest, bitmask

What is the best way to represent bit-mask values in JSON object?

For example:
we want to know what ingredients user want in his fruit salad

Orange = 0x01

Apple  = 0x02

Banana = 0x04

Grapes = 0x08

How would one represent the selected options in a JSON Object, obviously we can use integer value (i.e. 3 is for Orange and Apple) but it is not quite readable.

Is there are a better way?!

Answer (score 0):

Researching a bit on this topic uncovered the following case study:

https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/smartsheet-api-formatting

It's not exactly the same problem, but it was good for extrapolating some solutions here:

- Send a list of integers, from a predefined lookup table: e.g. [1, 3] (compromise between space and parsing)
- Send the actual bit mask value (harder to parse, takes the least space)
- Send a list of strings: e.g. [Orange, Banana] (easy to read, takes most space)

If space is not a constraint, I think the last options is the best.